# My code runs well with arrow function and using { }, but when { } are removed i'm getting syntax error

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I have been learning JavaScript. As I was going through arrow functions, I learned that the { } are not necessary when using arrow functions. Please help me understand.

This one works:

```
document.querySelector('.myForm').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.username.value);
    console.log(event.target.realname.value);
});
```

But if the { } are removed, it shows syntax error. The previous functions I worked with worked perfectly without the { }.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body

Comment: Well, you need "{}" which denotes the block for multiple lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The {} are used only when there are more than one statement. If there is only one statement , for example , there is no need of using { }

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple lines of code in your arrow function, you will need the `{}` and an explicit `return`. If there is a single line of code - an implicit return is assumed

Comment: Thank you for the info. when using { } i'm getting return without explicitly mentioning any. or is it that, if i explicitly use return only that line of code will be returned.

Comment: I think you are confused between `return` and `console.log`?

Comment: oh. yeah. got it. I got confused with return and console.log.